# event.currentTarget.innerHTML is empty in IE10 after view is re-rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10

Here is the [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/vuxoy/1/edit?html,js,console,output) (Please test in Chrome and IE10 to see the difference)

#### HTML

```
<body>
  <div id='a'>
    <button>CLick me</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### JS

```
var markup = '<button>CLick me</button>';

$('#a').on('click', 'button', function() {
  $('#a').html(markup);
});

$('#a').on('click', 'button', function(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.innerHTML); //.....(1)
});
```

Line (1) gives correct output in Chrome and Firefox while in IE10 I get empty string as the value of `event.currentTarget.innerHTML`. It only happens when `div(#a)` is rendered again.

PS: I am using `Backbone.js` in which I re-rendered the view but to make question simpler, I have refined the problem to above mentioned by taking backbone out of picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was curious so had a go. This won't answer your question but might point in the right direction

(1) In your example you replace a button with an identical button, if you replace it with different text you'll see in chrome that the innerHTML is actually the unreplaced text

(2) In IE `currentTarget` is an empty button with no parent

(3) It (sort of) works in IE and chrome if you do this:

```
event.delegateTarget.children[0].innerHTML
```

(4) doc type makes no difference either way

So your answer will be in finding the difference between delegateTarget and currentTarget, or just using delegateTarget

Comment: thanks a lot for the much useful information. +1. I really appreciate it.